# Numerical methods for nonlinear wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

What would be the best numerical method to solve nonlinear wave equation aka

$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=f(u)$
with initial and boundary conditions
$u(x,0) = \phi(x)$,
$u_{t}(x, 0) = 0$

Actually any information would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

What mathematical software tools do you have available?  It usually doesn't pay to reinvent the wheel.  In Maple you could do something like this:

> pde:= diff(u(x,t),t,t) = diff(u(x,t),x,x) + u(x,t)^2;
>
> ibc:= {u(0,t) = 1, D[2](u)(x,0) = 0, u(x,0)=1,u(1,t) = 1};
>
> solution:= pdsolve(pde,ibc, numeric,time=t,range = 0..1);

Comment: I tried with build in Matlab pde tool, but it solves only for non linearity $u$. I need to some method for more complicated. I was hoping that there is some numerical method that I could just implement, but could not find any so far. I never used Maple, although I am open to learn new thing. Can it solve pde for arbitrary non linearity and initial conditions?

Comment: AFAIK, the nonlinearity and initial/boundary conditions are arbitrary (of course you might run into numerical issues if they are too wild).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it.